# Need recommendations for a router for use with network cameras

Tags: router, ip-camera

I have a home LAN which has 5 desktop Apple and Windows machines, and 10 iOS tablets/phones) plus 5 wifi network cameras.  The cameras are on 24*7. The desktops are also on 24*7, while the iOS devices are intermittent (mostly in the evenings). I currently have a Netgear 8000 router and while I'm happy with its features, I am seeing a lot of loss of connectivity of the camera streams during the day - reachability drops off and then comes back, perhaps 1-10 times per day, connectivity is lost for at least a few minutes. I realize that ethernet connections are best but they are not practical for my application.

I have searched through a lot of router products' descriptions, but most of the performance claims are about gaming; my problem is that I do not know which of the specs to optimize, but otherwise am willing to spend up to $1000 on an appropriate router. I am looking for specific recommendations for a brand and model that is known to handle network camera streams without dropping connectivity. Additional requirements: I need at least (ideally more) 4 ethernet (hardware) ports, and I do currently use 3 other wireless access points as extenders to cover the whole distance and make sure that the cameras have full wifi bars (I could also move to mesh, if that is better than the scheme I have now).